# In Visual Studio Code, how do I disable all suggestions and other tool-tips?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've disabled every setting that appears to cause the suggestions and tool tips similar to the one below:

[screenshot of the tool-tip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnItS.png)

Here is a my settings.json:

```
{
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
"editor.fontSize": 24,
"editor.hover.enabled": false,
"editor.hover.sticky": false,
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
  },
"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10,
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "none",
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
"editor.wordWrap": "on",  "editor.hover.enabled": false,
"editor.parameterHints": false,
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
```

}

Is there any other setting that would stop these suggestions/tool-tips?

Here is another screenshot showing similar pop-up even after adding code suggested by P.W

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add one more option in your `settings.json` file.

```
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
```

Put it somewhere after

```
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
```

And see if it works.

Comment: Thanks. I added your suggested line and restarted VS Code, but I didn't notice a difference.  I added another image to my original question

Comment: What about the "html.suggest.html5" option, is it also false?

Comment: It wasn't 'html.suggest.html5' BUTyour earlier answer did help me to resolve it.  My settings.json had a setting written as 'editor.paramaterHints': false, however, in telling me where to place the 'editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions' setting you instructed to put it after 'editor.parameterHints.enabled'.  I had left off the 'enabled' from the key name.  After correcting the key name, the pop-up stopped.