How do I turn off all automatically-appearing suggestions and other "helpful" popups in VSCode, but still trigger them with a keyboard shortcut?
Whenever I type a dot or certain other characters, a popup like this shows up in VSCode, blocking my code and eating some of my keyboard input. It's gotten so bad I've developed a habit of hitting Escape before entering a newline, every time.
I like the code search/suggestion feature, but I want it to only appear when I trigger it manually. But there are literally dozens of similar-sounding settings in VSCode, I've turned off many that seemed relevant but it didn't do anything. How can I achieve the behavior I want?


See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349691/in-visual-studio-code-how-do-i-disable-all-suggestions-and-other-tool-tips

First of all, you should know that there are two different features in VSCode that create popups of this sort, which might at first glance look like the same thing. The first are suggestions, which show up when you type certain characters like a dot, to give you "autocomplete" options. The second are parameter hints, which show up while you are writing the parameters in a function call to tell you what that function accepts.
To turn off suggestions (as seen in the question), you want this setting:

The setting is called Editor > Suggest On Trigger Characters, and you want to disable it. There are several other settings that might seem relevant because they're called things like Inline suggest: Enabled/Disabled, but this setting here is the only one you want.
To set a keyboard shortcut to manually bring up suggestions, go to your keyboard settings and search for the Trigger Suggest command.
Parameter hints look like this:

To disable these, you want to disable the setting "Editor > Parameter Hints: Enabled":

The command you would want to set a keyboard shortcut for this is called Trigger Parameter Hints.
